# Customize wp_new_user_notification_email()

Tags: login, email

I am trying to customize the notification email sent to user that contains the link to set password.

Currently, I have set up a custom user registration and login forms at the urls `site.com/register` and `site.com/login` respectively.

After the registration, wordpress is sending email with following link that asks to set a password.

`site.com/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=XYieERXh3QinbU4VquB2&login=user%40gmail.com`

I want it replace this url to

`site.com/login?action=rp&key=XYieERXh3QinbU4VquB2&login=user%40gmail.com`

I have tried the following code in `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email', 'my_wp_new_user_notification_email', 10, 3 );

function my_wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {

    $message = sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user->user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __('Hello To set your password, visit the following address:') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= '<' . network_site_url("login/?key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user->user_login), 'login') . ">\r\n\r\n";


    $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = $message

    return $wp_new_user_notification_email;

}
```

I think I am missing `$key` information since the email received has the link like this:

`site.com/login?action=rp&key=&login=user%40test.com`

How to fix this?

Comment: It doesn't work for me, after pasting it in my Child theme function.php.
Could you help me ?

Comment: @Aurélien this isn't a discussion forum site, it's a Question/Answers site, so post comments as comments, not as answers

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `get_password_reset_key` function [(see reference)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_password_reset_key/) which will query the database and return the reset password key of the user.

Here's a full working example:

```
add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 10, 3 );

function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {
    $key = get_password_reset_key( $user );
    $message = sprintf(__('Welcome to the Community,')) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= 'To set your password, visit the following address:' . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user->user_login), 'login') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "After this you can enjoy our website!" . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "Kind regards," . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Support Office Team" . "\r\n";
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = $message;

    $wp_new_user_notification_email['headers'] = 'From: MyName<example@domain.ext>'; // this just changes the sender name and email to whatever you want (instead of the default WordPress <wordpress@domain.ext>

    return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
}
```

Comment: Some explanation why your code would solve OP's question would be nice.

Comment: I edited my answer. Do you think it's ok now?

Comment: Yes, this is better. Now you have explained the key component of your solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to assign the generated key to your variable `$key`, which is currently undefined.

You could work around this by attaching another function to the `retrieve_password_key` action, which fires just after WordPress generates the key.  From its name I would think it exists just for this purpose.

```
function wpse306642_stash_key( $user_login, $key ) {
    global $wpse306642_new_user_key;
    $wpse306642_new_user_key = $key;
}

add_action( 'retrieve_password_key', 'wpse306642_stash_key', 10, 2 );
```

Then replace `$key` in your function with `$wpse306642_new_user_key`, declaring it as global at the start of the function.

Using a global just for this does feel a little hacky, but it should work.